# Setting cwd in modern C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am playing around with MSVC's `<experimental/filesystem>` library, trying to reset my current working directory to be the executable directory.

This is because when building and running my project in VS2017, the cwd is actually `$(ProjectDir)`, rather than `$(OutputDir)`, as I would expect. I am aware that I [could change this in Visual Studio](https://codeyarns.com/2013/12/30/how-to-change-working-directory-in-visual-studio/), but I'd like to dummy-proof my code as well.

To that end, I have this snippet of code I am using to reset my path at the beginning of main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Utils::resetcwd(argc, argv);
...
```

I would like to know if there is anything that I am doing that is "evil" or would not be cross-platform compatible (assuming the filesystem library does not undergo any major changes).

I know that on *nix systems, using argv[0] to find the cwd is not guaranteed to return an absolute path, but I can't find much on what are valid constructors for the `Path` class. In fact, I'm surprised that the following works:

```
namespace Utils
{
    using namespace std::experimental;

    static void resetcwd(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        std::string execution(argv[0]);
        auto basePath = execution.substr(0, execution.find_last_of("/"));

        if (basePath.length() == execution.length())
        {
            basePath = execution.substr(0, execution.find_last_of("\\"));
        }

        filesystem::current_path(basePath);
    }
}
```

Basically, have I done the right thing, according to C++ 2017?

Comment: If you're *ever* playing with a path without using the actual `path` type, then no, you're not using the filesystem library right.

Comment: @NicolBolas How would you recommend getting the cwd as a `Path` then? Not something I've found any resources on so far. It smelled a bit to me, too.

Comment: Well, let's think about this for a second. You found a function called `current_path` that *sets* the current working directory. So the term "current path" seems to be how the filesystem refers to that sort of thing. It might occur to you to consider searching for other functions that have the words "current path" in them. It also might occur to you to see if there are [*other overloads* of `current_path`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path).

Comment: Apologies @NicolBolas - I realised that I misspoke in my previous comment - I actually want to get the directory of the executable! The cwd is easy enough to get (with current_path(), as you mentioned). But I have no idea how to get the _executable_ directory as a `Path`.

Comment: Getting the executable's directory is an entirely separate question from getting or setting the cwd (which is what your question title asks for). You should change your question to make it clear what you're looking for.